# Contact names dont match numbers in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to access phone numbers with names.But When I do this ,My calling don"t match my chosen number.I have a listview that has a checkbox.User "s select to names and these names go to second activity with numbers.My problem is in second activity that numbers and names  selected at first activity.When I call the any name ,My application is calling different number.How can I fix it ?

```
     ArrayList<String> listte = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> selectedlist = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView chosinglist;
        Button kaydet;
        ArrayList<String> listtearama = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> selectedlistarama = new ArrayList<>();
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                chosinglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chosing);
                chosinglist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                getNumber(this.getContentResolver());



            }

            private void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
                Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
               String     phonenumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    System.out.println(".................." + phonenumber);


                   if (!listte.contains(name)){ // it doesn"t work.But if It doesn"t exist, listview is repeating yourself.
                    listte.add(name);


                   }

                    if (!listtearama.contains(phonenumber)){// it doesn"t work.But if It doesn"t exist, listview is repeating yourself.
                        listtearama.add(phonenumber);  }

                }
                phones.close();// close cursor

                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkrow,
                        R.id.checkedTextView2, listte);


   chosinglist.setAdapter(adapter);
        chosinglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String selecteditem = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                int arkaplandakinumaraposition = parent.getPositionForView(view);


                String aramakicinliste = listtearama.get(arkaplandakinumaraposition);


                if (selectedlistarama.contains(aramakicinliste)) {
                    selectedlistarama.remove(aramakicinliste);
                } else
                    selectedlistarama.add(aramakicinliste);


                if (selectedlist.contains(selecteditem)) {
                    selectedlist.remove(selecteditem);

                } else selectedlist.add(selecteditem);
```

[image]

Comment: Add an android ,java tag to your question, for more people show interest. Also your code is not very descriptive so it's a bit hard to grasp what you are doing, try using descriptive variable names or comments

Comment: ok  I added android tag.

Comment: ok.I have editted my codo little bit.İf you are thinging  .just say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> listte = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> selectedlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView chosinglist;
    Button kaydet;
    ArrayList<String> listtearama = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> selectedlistarama = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        chosinglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chosing);
        chosinglist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        getNumber(this.getContentResolver());


    }

    private void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        //first of all, check if the cursor has data
        if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {
            //move to the first element, the cursor might be at an invalid location
            phones.moveToFirst();
            do {

                String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phonenumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                System.out.println(".................." + phonenumber);


                if (!listte.contains(name)) { // it doesn"t work.But It doesn"t exist listview repeating yourself.
                    listte.add(name);
                }

                if (!listtearama.contains(phonenumber)) {// it doesn"t work.But It doesn"t exist listview repeating yourself.
                    listtearama.add(phonenumber);
                }

            } while (phones.moveToNext());
            phones.close();// close cursor
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkrow,
                R.id.checkedTextView2, listte);


        chosinglist.setAdapter(adapter);
        chosinglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selecteditem = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                //int arkaplandakinumaraposition = parent.getPositionForView(view); irrelevant to me


                String aramakicinliste = listtearama.get(position);


                if (selectedlistarama.contains(aramakicinliste)) {
                    selectedlistarama.remove(aramakicinliste);
                } else
                    selectedlistarama.add(aramakicinliste);


                if (selectedlist.contains(selecteditem)) {
                    selectedlist.remove(selecteditem);

                } else selectedlist.add(selecteditem);
            }

        });
    }

    /*From what I see, it seems you rather need to implement multiple selection because the checkbox 
    * has an onclick event of its own which is different from the one for the entire list item*/
```

This updated answer makes sure the selected items are correct, your implementation of transferring the data will be the deciding factor now.

Comment: It doesn"t work. Program is still calling diffrent numbers.

Comment: It may seem you are clicking on checkboxes rather than the actual list item, I will write a full implementation of what you want to do shortly so you can compare.